# Cannot send email to Google Apps alias from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, gmail, hotmail

I'm using Wordpress and sending email via Gmail SMTP:

- server: `smtp.gmail.com`
- port: `465`

I created Google Apps main domain called `domain.com` and email `info@domain.com`.
Then I registered domain aliases for `domain.com`.

I have more different domains/sites: `domain1.com`, `domain2.com`.

When I try to send email to `info@domain.com` from Wordpress site (e.g. `www.domain1.com`), it works. If I try to send email to any alias (e.g. `info@domain1.com` or `info@domain2.com`), it doesn't. I don't know why.

For your information, if I try to send email from my Hotmail account it works, I can send to all aliases.

Comment: What problem do you see?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636921/cannot-send-email-from-php-using-gmail-smtp

Comment: Do you have the right MX records set up for domain1.com and domain2.com?

Comment: how it differs from my previous question:  I already compiled PHP with openssl so now I can send email. This is different question. Now I can send only to main domain registered in google aps, but cannnot send to domain aliases. MX records are ok for those domains . As I said sending from e.g hotmail works ok

Answer (score 1):

You appear to by trying use the Gmail SMTP server as an [open relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay).   Mail servers are no longer configured such that you can send email from anybody to anybody else.  I would expect you to be able to use the GMail SMTP server only to send email from your GMail address.

Google may be allowing mail to go through when it is to your own domain, but is dropping other mail as likely spam